# Adicionar parágrafo com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa noite, estou tentando adicionar um parágrafo quando clicou no botão mas não está funcionando e não consigo saber o porque, alguem poderia ajudar?

```
<script>

          $("#btAdd").click(function(){
                var texto = document.getElementById("t").value;
                $("#new").append("<p>"+texto+"</p>");
            });
</script>
```

e no HTML está assim:

```
<div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="t"/>
        <input type="button"
                value="Adicionar parágrafo" id="btAdd" /> <br><br>
        <input type="button"
                value="Aumentar tamanho fonte" id="btAumentarFonte" />
        <input type="button"
                value="Diminuir tamanho fonte" id="btDiminuirFonte" /><br><br>
        <input type="button"
                value="Remover último parágrafo" id="btRemoverUltimo" />
        <input type="button"
                value="Remover todos os parágrafo" id="btRemoverTodos" />
        </div>
        
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <div id="new"></div>
```

Comment: A parte de `script` e `html` estão no mesmo arquivo? Qual versão da biblioteca `jQuery` está utilizando?

Comment: @Rfroes87 Estão, estou usando <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> para a biblioteca do jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite!

o seu script esta dessa forma

> 

```
      $("#btAdd").click(function(){
            var texto = document.getElementById("t").value;
            $("#new").append("<p>"+texto+"</p>");
        });
```

Você precisa adicionar o seu JQuery dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ <<CODE>> });
```

dessa forma tudo que voce colocar dentro dessa instrução irá ser executado.

codigo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btAdd").click(function(){
            var texto =$("#t").val();
            $("#new").html("<p>"+texto+"</p>");
        });
});
</script>
```

O $("#new").html('<>') adiciona as instruções html dentro do **#new**

Ps: é necessario chamar o script do JQuery antes da do script do seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Opa Eduardo!

Adaptei o seu script para utilizar o Jquery na hora que pegar o valor do input

```js
$("#btAdd").click(addText)

function addText () {
  const text = "<p>"+$("#t").val()+"</p";
  $("#new").append(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="t"/>
        <input type="button"
                value="Adicionar parágrafo" id="btAdd" /> <br><br>
        <input type="button"
                value="Aumentar tamanho fonte" id="btAumentarFonte" />
        <input type="button"
                value="Diminuir tamanho fonte" id="btDiminuirFonte" /><br><br>
        <input type="button"
                value="Remover último parágrafo" id="btRemoverUltimo" />
        <input type="button"
                value="Remover todos os parágrafo" id="btRemoverTodos" />
        </div>
        
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <div id="new"></div>
```